# Extinction time distribution in stochastic system

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, biology

I have seen in different work of stochastic predator-prey model that extinction time follows a lognormal distribution and I have also tested it in a model. Can anyone please tell me what is the reason behind that extinction time follows a lognormal distribution?

My thought: I think population growth is a multiplicative process and if there is a disease in the system death is also a multiplicative process. Is it correct? Please help me.

Comment: Can you cite the "different work of stochastic predator-prey model" that you are referring to?

Comment: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16995621/  https://science.sciencemag.org/content/344/6187/1246752 https://academic.oup.com/bioscience/article/51/5/341/243981https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1034/j.1600-0706.2002.11962.x